# How do I force Jetty's Maven plugin to close its file handles?

Tags: java, maven, jetty

I am developing a web application using Maven and I am using Jetty's plugin (`mvn jetty:run`) to speed up development. Unfortunately, the plugin appears to keep static files open (such as JavaScript files), thus preventing me from saving subsequent changes. My only solution so far is to restart the server, but that wastes a lot of time.

How can I force Jetty's Maven plugin to release its file handles to static resources?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jetty Maven Plugin is ignoring custom webdefault.xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988019/jetty-maven-plugin-is-ignoring-custom-webdefault-xml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Files+locked+on+Windows

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>useFileMappedBuffer</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value> <!-- change to false -->
</init-param>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work on jetty 9 on windows 7 32 bit

Comment: I've tried this with jetty 9.3.0.M2 9.3.0.R0 and 9.3.0.R1 which are the last versions to use java 7. It doesn't seem to be the solution. If i find a solution i'll post it here.